# Require assistance to write Query joining 3 tables

Tags: mysql, query-performance, join, query, pivot

I have a table called `form_submission_entries` which contains data like this:

| id | submission_id | field_id | value |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 1 | John |
| 2 | 1 | 2 | Doe |
| 3 | 1 | 3 | 27 |
| 4 | 2 | 1 | Jane |
| 5 | 2 | 2 | Doe |
| 6 | 2 | 3 | 23 |

The field_id corresponds to a `form_fields` table which looks like this:

| id | name | title |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | first_name | First Name |
| 2 | last_name | Last Name |
| 3 | age | Age |

And of course a `form_submissions` table which looks like this:

| id | form_id | submitted_at |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 2021-11-05 08:16:27 |
| 2 | 1 | 2021-11-05 08:28:11 |

I would like to run a single query that will allow me to create a CSV file that looks like this:

| submission_id | first_name | last_name | age | submitted_at |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | John | Doe | 27 | 2021-11-05 08:16:27 |
| 2 | Jane | Doe | 23 | 2021-11-05 08:28:11 |

I am able to achieve this by creating multiple queries. First by getting a list of ids from the `form_submissions`. Then using that list of ids to create multiple queries to fetch data from the `form_submission_entries` using the `submission_id`. But it looks nasty. I was hoping someone somewhere would have a much better approach. Thanks so much!

Comment: Could you post the statements that you already have? That would help the community know where your problems might be.

Comment: A better approach would be to redesign form_submission_entries so that it corresponds to the layout of the form.  It would make your query a lot simpler, and the same goes for any application using that data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your schema and goal, there are a couple of different ways you can achieve this. This is one way you can get the output you're looking for:

```
SELECT 
    FS.id AS submission_id, 
    FirstName.value AS first_name,
    LastName.value AS last_name,
    Age.value AS age,
    FS.submitted_at
FROM form_submissions FS
LEFT JOIN form_submission_entries FirstName
    ON FS.id = FirstName.submission_id
    AND FirstName.field_id = 1
LEFT JOIN form_submission_entries LastName
    ON FS.id = LastName.submission_id
    AND LastName.field_id = 2
LEFT JOIN form_submission_entries Age
    ON FS.id = Age.submission_id
    AND Age.field_id = 3
```

The query should be fairly self-explanatory but essentially it starts with the parent `form_submissions` table and joins to the child `form_submission_entries` three times, each time only on a specific entry. I'm using `LEFT JOIN` (which is an outer join) just in case any of your entries are not required. If they are all required and all three will always exist for a given submission then you can switch the `LEFT JOIN`s to `INNER JOIN`s instead.

Finally to turn the above SQL result set into a CSV output, you just have to concatenate the columns in the `SELECT` list with commas, and union in your headers, like so:

```
SELECT 
    CONCAT
    (
        'submission_id', ',',
        'first_name', ',',
        'last_name', ',',
        'age', ',',
        'submitted_at'
    )

UNION ALL

SELECT 
    CONCAT
    (
        FS.id, ',',
        FirstName.value, ',',
        LastName.value, ',',
        Age.value, ',',
        FS.submitted_at
    )
FROM form_submissions FS
LEFT JOIN form_submission_entries FirstName
    ON FS.id = FirstName.submission_id
    AND FirstName.field_id = 1
LEFT JOIN form_submission_entries LastName
    ON FS.id = LastName.submission_id
    AND LastName.field_id = 2
LEFT JOIN form_submission_entries Age
    ON FS.id = Age.submission_id
    AND Age.field_id = 3
```